# MediaMetadataRetriever setdatasource IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception

I am new to Android and to this site so sorry for the questions that might be trivial.

I have a problem with setDataSource MediaMetadataRetriever (I have installed also FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever and the problem is even worse).

My files are in /storage/removable/stdcard1//DCIM/... All files have been taken either with this mobile (Sony Z running 4.3) or Samsung S2,S4. I have tried to copy some of the files to the internal memory and I get the same issue

I have tried to access them with FileDesriptor and filepath.

The problem is the following:
with the original MediaMetadataRetriever : some of the files taken with this phone AND ALL of those taken with Samsung are raising the  are IllegalArgumentException.
with the FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever ALL files are raising IllegalArgumentException.

I have installed my app on Samsung S3, S4 and Moto G and get the same problem.
Can someone help me?

thank you

Comment: Did you add "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />" to your manifest? I wrote FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever and I can guarantee there is no way all of those files are failing with an IllegalArgumentException if you are providing the correct path.

Comment: yes I did. many thanks for the reminder. Actually afer a day of searching (again I am new to Androdi) i figured out that the metadata is not linked ot a file but to a database maintained by Android. Thus some files do not have metadata and the Retriever raises the exception.